# Exporting all data from table using laravel backpack

Tags: laravel

I want to export all data from the products table which has more than 10k products in it. I'm using the backpack in this project and while clicking export csv only the current page will be exported. Any solution for this?
 Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The export functionality is currently handled by the JS Datatable. So I'm not sure if an export with over 10k entries would work. This could be the reason why just the current page will get exported.

But I've found a little workaround. The following is stated in the Laravel Backpack docs ([Link](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/crud-operation-list-entries#export-buttons)) about export:

```
Please note that when clicked, each button will export the currently visible table. You can use 
the "visibility" button, and the "Items per page" dropdown to manipulate what is inside the export.
```

So try to change the amount of items in your table by using the `Visibility` option in the dropdown or the `Items per page` selection under the table to export more than just one page.

I hope this will work for now and someone else can find a solution to export everything.

Comment: I even tried the same. but what happened is because of data (more than 12k), it takes around 1 minute and crashes